# Avoid splitting data on commas (within quotation marks) in SQL?

Tags: mysql, csv, load-data-infile, truncated

I am trying to load a .csv file into a MySQL table, but I'm running into the following error message: "ERROR 1262 (01000): Row 304 was truncated; it contained more data than there were input columns."

Here is the code I'm using:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'my_taxpayers.csv'
INTO TABLE taxpayers
FIELDS ENCLOSED BY '"'
TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS;
```

I've pasted Row 304, the first row that causes a problem, below. The corresponding column headers for the row are

```
PARCEL, TAXPAYER, ADDRESS_1, ADDRESS_2, CITY, STATE, ZIP, COUNTRY, ROLE_PERCENTAGE and IN_CARE_OF.
```

```
*00.000366,"BUNNEY, GARY LEE",40 E TRENT,,SPOKANE,WA,99202,,100.0,**"CAROL LUNDY, 1ST AMERICAN"***
```

It appears the data is getting split (which I don't want) when it runs into `"CAROL LUNDY, 1ST AMERICAN"` and maybe `"BUNNEY, GARY LEE"`. I thought the `ENCLOSED BY '"'` was supposed to solve that, so I'm stuck.

For more context, here are a few more random rows of the .csv file that DIDN'T cause any issues.

```
00.000102,ANITA'S DAPPER DOGS,727 E 32ND AVE,,SPOKANE,WA,99203,,100.0,ANITA ANN SYKES
00.000103,"MKY INVESTMENTS, INC",9508 N DIVISION ST,,SPOKANE,WA,99218,,100.0,MARK & KAREN YOO
00.000104,COUNTY RECORD'S PUBLISHING CO,503 E ERMINA AVE,,SPOKANE,WA,99207,,100.0,JILL MARIE BUSWELL
00.000105,DANCAR MECHANICAL INC,311 N HODGES RD,,SPOKANE VALLEY,WA,99016,,100.0,DANIEL F SCHROER
00.000106,ARTHUR ARMS ADULT FAMILY HOME,652 S ARTHUR ST,,SPOKANE,WA,99202,,100.0,ANTHONY R JONES
```

Comment: are the ** part of the data?

Comment: You must use OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was I needed to be doing

LINES TERMINATED BY `\r\n`

Adding in the `r` fixes everything.